.profile from Linux on Windows
I'm working on a project where I need to implement a login screen that appears immediately after entering the username, but before establishing any connection to the system. This behavior is similar to how Linux utilizes the .profile file for executing commands upon user login.
I want the system to display a login screen where the user can input their password, a login screen I made with Python. Only after successful authentication, the system should proceed with establishing the connection and loading the user environment.
How can I do this, similar to the .profile file on Linux, but on Windows?
I tried many approaches to this issue, setting it into the Initialize folder, and then running when the computer starts, adding it to the Regedit so it would start, but it is all slow, it starts after you entered the user, not before, like Linux does.

On Linux, the profile is just a file with commands that a particular shell executes when the login program runs it. This happens after the user authenticates. It is rather unclear what you want to happen on Windows. If you want to run e.g bash as a shell, just do it, it will read .profile the exact same way ut does on Linux.

Are you trying to put something on top of the Windows lock screen, or do you want a command line terminal to be shown after logging in? It is possible to replace the lock screen but it's not easy. This might be a question for superuser.com, where it's more about the workings of the operating system rather than programming. To accomplish what you want, you'd need to replace the LockApp.exe or another executable that is ran before boot. Then, after you are done you can forward to the original executable and use automatic login to avoid the built in login prompt. This is very insecure though.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I need it to execute the screen just like linux, before the user has access to the desktop, but the standard initialize with system ways dont work for me, because they're executed after.

I think you are at the wrong place, this is not a programming questiom, this is an OS administraion question.
